# Verilog - confusion between || and + operator

Tags: verilog, boolean-algebra

In boolean algebra, addition of terms corresponds to an OR gate, while multiplication corresponds to an AND gate.

Suppose I wanted a blower fan of a thermostat that worked as follows:

> The fan should turn on if either the heater or air-conditioner are on. Alternatively if the user requests the fan to turn on (by turning on an input *fan_on*), the fan should turn on even if the heater or air conditioner are off.

Based on these requirements I formulated the logic statement in Verilog code as:

```
assign blower_fan = fan_on + heater + aircon;
```

However upon simulation this yields an incorrect solution. However this works:

```
assign blower_fan = fan_on || (heater + aircon);
```

as does

```
assign blower_fan = fan_on || (heater || aircon);
```

**My Question:**

What am I misunderstanding about the + operator? Also, I'm confused between the latter two solutions that DO work - why do both of them work and is the last one where I use only the logical OR operator a more correct (or preferred) way of doing what I want to do?

Edit#1: Here is the whole module where I declared inputs and outputs

```
module top_module (
    input too_cold,
    input too_hot,
    input mode,
    input fan_on,
    output heater,
    output aircon,
    output fan
); 

    assign heater = (mode&&too_cold);
    assign aircon = (!mode&&too_hot);
    assign fan = (fan_on) || (heater || aircon);

endmodule
```

Comment: In the problem it could be safely assumed that both a and h wouldn't be = 1 at the same time. Which is why that wasn't a test case. But ginginsha's 2nd comment was very helpful as that explained why that attempt turned out to be right although it was flawed. 

My mistake was in confusing Boolean arithmetic with the '+' operator which in Verilog is used as an arithmetic operator! Well oops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boolean expression for OR and AND are `||` and `&&` respectively.

The `+` symbol is actually the arithmetic expression

```
a = 2'b01 // 1
b = 2'b01 // 1
a + b = 2'b10 // 1 + 1 = 2
a || b = 2'b01 // 1 OR 1 = 1
```

Source: https://www.utdallas.edu/~akshay.sridharan/index_files/Page5212.htm

EDIT:

The two following statements are logically equivalent

```
assign fan = (fan_on) || (heater || aircon);
assign fan = fan_on || heater || aircon;
```

The problem with

```
assign blower_fan = fan_on + heater + aircon;
```

is that if two inputs are high (e.g. heater = 1, aircon = 1, fan_on = 0), then blower_fan (which is assumed to be 1 bit) has overflowed, and therefore will be 0 (1'b1 + 1'b1 = 1'b0).

Comment: Um in the source you gave me it says that || and && are logical operators which is what I need right? Rather than the bitwise operators?

Comment: Right, sorry about that. The logical OR evaluates to true as long as none of the operands are 0's. The problem may be that in the **assign blower_fan = fan_on + heater + aircon;** case, there is overflow to blower_fan.

Comment: This makes sense! And helps me understand why the second one turned out to give the right test solution even though the logic is wrong. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The Verilog `+` operator is *not* the an OR operator, it is the addition operator. There are two OR operators in Verilog:

```
|   bitwise OR 
||  logical OR
```

For vectors, the *bitwise* operation treats the individual bits of vector operands separately. In contrast, with the *logical* operators a scalar or vector is considered to be TRUE when it includes at least one 1, and FALSE when every bit is 0. Xs and Zs are considered to be unknown (neither TRUE nor FALSE).

You can also use the `|` operator as a *reduction operator*.

For example:

```
Expression           Result    Comment
=========================================
   1'b0 |  1'b0      1'b0      bitwise OR
   1'b0 |  1'b1      1'b1      bitwise OR
   1'b1 |  1'b0      1'b1      bitwise OR
   1'b1 |  1'b1      1'b1      bitwise OR

4'b0101 |  4'b1100   4'b1101   bitwise OR

4'b0000 || 4'b0000   1'b0      logical OR
4'b0000 || 4'b1100   1'b1      logical OR
4'b0101 || 4'b0000   1'b1      logical OR
4'b0101 || 4'b1100   1'b1      logical OR

| 4'b0000            1'b0      reduction
| 4'b0101            1'b1      reduction
| 4'b1111            1'b1      reduction
```

If you use the `+` operator instead of the `|` operator and assign to one-bit, you are effectively using exclusive-OR instead of OR. Compare these truth tables:

```
            OR     XOR    +
A    B      F      F      F   
==============================
1'b0 1'b0   1'b0   1'b0   1'b0
1'b0 1'b1   1'b1   1'b1   1'b1
1'b1 1'b0   1'b1   1'b1   1'b1
1'b1 1'b1   1'b1   1'b0   1'b0
```

This expression:

```
assign blower_fan = fan_on || (heater + aircon);
```

is going to fail when the `fan_on` is `1'b0` and both `heater` and `aircon` are `1'b1`, whereas this one won't:

```
assign blower_fan = fan_on | heater | aircon;
```